# Compiler check to ensure I'm running in bare-metal and not in a hosted environment

Tags: c, compilation, cross-compiling, bare-metal

If I'm compiling a C program for bare-metal, I know I can insert things like

```
#if defined(__linux__) 
#error "You're not using a cross-compiler."
#endif`
```

But, I don't want to check for every operating system. Is there a single check to see if I'm in a hosted environment?

Comment: you're going to compile on baremetal?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes. Updated question for clarity.

Comment: I know you compile _for_ baremetal, but are you planning to run the compiler _on_ baremetal. Probably not.

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood. Correct, I am running on bare-metal, but compiling elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, so for you what is a hosted environment? since you cannot run your compiler on baremetal, what's the use of testing about linux, windows whatever? and why do you mind if someone can compile your code on a TI99-4A as long as it works? (sorry for all those questions... can't figure out your problem)

Comment: A hosted environment in my case would be any operating system. I only want it as a failsafe to prevent accidentally using the wrong compiler or forgetting the --ffreestanding flag.
I appreciate the questions! I'm new at this, so I might not be using all the right terminology.

Comment: so what is your accepted machine to build your code? (still not getting it!)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being clear. I don't care where it's built. Building on macOS, linux, whatever. I just want it to be free standing and only run on bare-metal.

Comment: If it is freestanding code to run on bare metal it will contain stuff that won't compile in Linux, Windows whatever? Anyway, if it has to be compiled by a cross-compiler, won't that be target specific, and have some `#define` of its own?

Comment: you cannot detect if you're running on bare metal at compile time! you have to find a way to detect baremetal at _runtime_. Compiler flags won't help you there.

Comment: I can check if I'm compiling for linux (per my example in the original question). Is there a more generic check I can use that's not linux specific, but would be true for any OS?

Comment: You said your compiler `#error` is "You're not using a cross-compiler." So if you want a single check, then check for that specific cross-compiler that you know is good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to determine that you are building with `-ffreestanding` then make your code check for the `__STDC_HOSTED__` macro. It will be set to 1 for normal code and set to 0 for a freestanding build.

See the GCC info pages or the docs. The relevant quote is

> By default, it acts as the compiler for a hosted
>   implementation, defining '**STDC_HOSTED**' as '1' and presuming that
>   when the names of ISO C functions are used, they have the semantics
>   defined in the standard.  To make it act as a conforming freestanding
>   implementation for a freestanding environment, use the option
>   '-ffreestanding'; it then defines '**STDC_HOSTED**' to '0' and does not
>   make assumptions about the meanings of function names from the standard
>   library, with exceptions noted below.